# How to find the CMake command line I used for the build?

Tags: cmake

This is what typically happens. I get source code that has cmake build scripts. I create a `build` subdirectory, change to it, run `cmake <options> ..`. Depending upon the project and its dependencies I have to repeat the last step until it finds all necessary dependencies and generates makefiles. I successfully build and use the project. Few days pass, I forget about this installation. Then one day I'm trying to setup the same project on another machine and now I can't recall what exact CMake command line I used in the past to get things working.

I still have the old build directory on the old machine. Can I find the cmake command line I used in the past, by looking into some of the autogenerated files in the build directory? I was expecting CMake would just put the exact command line I used in one of these files in commented form. But if it does so, I haven't found it yet.

How can I find the original CMake command line I used?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*You can't.*

Original CMake command can be guessed from analysis of `CMakeCache.txt`

As a workaround, you could always create a simple wrapper to store the original command line used. Something along these lines:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$@" > cmake_command.log
$@
```

Comment: How? I have a CMakeCache.txt but it includes every single possible setting. My command line was much simpler, but still tricky enough that I don't remember everything that was previously set. Is there a trick to getting the actual command line from CMakeCache.txt?

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing, and as it stands, this does not actually answer the question. Perhaps the answer is as simple as _"You can't."_, which this seems to hint at.

Comment: I hate projects that use Cmake for this.

Comment: I like this answer because at least now I can stop looking. Still, big frowny face for CMake not storing something so potentially useful, especially when everything else imaginable is saved.

Comment: @VladimirF is there another build system that provides this functionality?

Comment: @JohnDeBord configure always saves the full command line in `config.log`, so anybody who has ever built anything using it would naturally expect this from CMake too.

Comment: @VZ I had no idea. Didn't even bother to check. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, @peter-petrik! In case anyone needs it as a standalone command and interchangeable with cmake (released on conda): https://github.com/cartoonist/cmache